# Query to a torrent tracker in node.js

Tags: node.js, bittorrent, tracker

I was looking for a node.js implementation to query a torrent tracker (http, udp or whatever) to get seeds, peers and downloads

What I found was only a tracker server implementation, and before implementing it myself I ask here if anybody has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a bitTorrent client in node.js which will hit a http tracker.  my repo is https://github.com/rtjoseph11/nTorrent.  if you look in the utils file the tracker request is there.  for a detailed explanation of what to include in a request go to https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification

Comment: Please try always to include code/explanation here to avoid linking the answer. If the link dies one day, your answer get useless. Cheers.

Comment: great ! After a short look, i guess you implemented only the http query, right?

Comment: yea I only implemented http.  There is a udp spec online as well that I'm going to use.  Thats probably next up in terms of features for me.